# VS Code - Flake8

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Boa tarde,

No código abaixo, o from e o raio ** 2 não estão sendo reconhecidos.
Ao verificar o erro com o from, aparece a seguinte mensagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser este problema?

Comment: Boa noite! Não coloque seu código como imagem, as pessoas precisam reproduzir seu código com rapidez!

Comment: Sim, tens razão, não tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado pela dica, boa noite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está em:

```
raio = input("Informe o raio: ")
```

Isso ocorre porque você não está definindo o ***tipo de variável (int,str,float,bool)*** que o input vai receber. Por padrão o input no python sempre vai receber uma ***String*** que tem seu tipo definido como ***str*** ou seja não está recebendo um valor numérico.

- Portanto o python está tentando elevar a 2 uma ***String*** e não um ***int que é um valor númerico***  por isso que está dando erro.

> Para resolver basta definir o tipo de input da seguinte forma:

```
raio = int(input("Informe o raio: "))
```

> Ou também caso você queira utilizar um número com ponto flutuante ***(Números quebrados):***

```
raio = float(input("Informe o raio: "))
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Perfeito Lucas, muito bem explicado e realmente funcionou. Muitíssimo obrigado.